# How to safely quit a Toplevel() window on a thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, thread-safety

I want to include a spinner in my program to show some indication that program is doing something when some heavy background calculations are being made. Here is the spinner I came up with, but I am having trouble quitting it safely. I am not sure how else I can make my idea work, and this is my latest code for it. Anyone have any hint on how I can implement this functionality?

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


class Spinner_top(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, text = None, barsize = 10, speed = 0.10, spinnerSize = 50):
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.barsize = barsize
        self.speed = speed
        self.size = spinnerSize
        self.done = False
        if text is None:
            self.text = 'Program is thinking, thus progress is moving'
        else:
            self.text = text
        self.title(self.text)
        self.out = tk.Label(master = self,
                            height = 1,
                            borderwidth = 0,
                            width = 80,
                            bg = self['background'])
        self.out.pack()
        self.update()
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.fill_self)
        self.thread.start()

    def fill_self(self):
        print('start called')
#        print(self)
#        print('update2')
        forward = True
        progress = 0
        print('entered while loop')
        while True:
            msg = self.spinnerCalc(progress)
            print('message changed')
            self.out.configure(text = msg)
            print('message updated')
            self.update()
            print('updated self')
            if forward:
                if progress == self.size - self.barsize:
                    forward = False
                    progress -= 1
                else:
                    progress += 1
            else:
                if progress == 0:
                    forward = True
                    progress += 1
                else:
                    progress -= 1
            print(self.done)
            if self.done:
                break
            sleep(self.speed)
        return

    def spinnerCalc(self, progress):
        bar = '|'
        barsize = self.barsize
        size = self.size
        for i in range (progress):
            bar += '-'
        for i in range (barsize):
            bar += '\u2588'
        for i in range (size-barsize-progress):
            bar += '-'
        bar += '|'
        return bar

    def stop(self):
        print('stop called')
        self.done = True
        self.thread.join()
        print('got pass join()')
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
spinner = [None]
def start():
    if spinner[0] is None:
        spinner[0] = Spinner_top(root,'Program is thinking')
def stop():
    if spinner[0] is not None:
        spinner[0].stop()
        spinner[0] = None
def experiment():
    if spinner[0] is None:
        spinner[0] = Spinner_top(root,'Try something')
        spinner[0].stop()
tk.Button(root,
          text = 'start spinner',
          command = start).pack()
tk.Button(root,
          text = 'stop spinner',
          command = stop).pack()
tk.Button(root,
          text='experiment',
          command = experiment).pack()
tk.Button(root,
          text = 'quit',
          command = root.destroy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am running into 2 problems with this:
1. When starting using the 'start spinner' button, the program freezes up.
2. When starting with the 'experiment' button, the code cannot get to print('message updated') line.

```
#trying to use the spinner using after as per @Nae suggestion (resulted in more problems :/
class Spinner_top(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, text = None, barsize = 10, speed = 100, spinnerSize = 50):
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.barsize = barsize
        self.speed = speed
        self.size = spinnerSize
        self.progress = 0
        self.done = False
        if text is None:
            self.text = 'Program is thinking, thus progress is moving'
        else:
            self.text = text
        self.title(self.text)
        self.out = tk.Label(master = self,
                            height = 1,
                            borderwidth = 0,
                            width = 80,
                            bg = self['background'])
        self.out.pack()
        self.fill_self()

    def fill_self(self):
        print('start called')
#        print(self)
#        print('update2')
        self.forward = True
        progress = 0
        print('entered while loop')
        def foo():
            msg = self.spinnerCalc(progress)
            print('message changed')
            self.out.configure(text = msg)
            print('message updated')
            self.update()
            print('updated self')
            if self.forward:
                if self.progress == self.size - self.barsize:
                    self.forward = False
                    self.progress -= 1
                else:
                    self.progress += 1
            else:
                if progress == 0:
                    self.forward = True
                    self.progress += 1
                else:
                    self.progress -= 1
#            print(self.done)
            if not self.done:
                self.after(self.speed, func = foo)
        foo()
        return

    def spinnerCalc(self, progress):
        bar = '|'
        barsize = self.barsize
        size = self.size
        for i in range (progress):
            bar += '-'
        for i in range (barsize):
            bar += '\u2588'
        for i in range (size-barsize-progress):
            bar += '-'
        bar += '|'
        return bar

    def stop(self):
        print('stop called')
        self.done = True
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()
```

After trying to figure this out, I have just resorted to simple spinner. Better than nothing and technically does the job. If anyone finds a way to make this spinner idea work with an updating gui though, I'd appreciate it.

```
class Simple_Spinner(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master,text=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grab_set()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.do_nothing)
        if text is None:
            text = 'Program is processing'
        tk.Label(self,text=text).pack()
        self.update()

    def do_nothing(self):
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.grab_release()
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: Why do you use `sleep`? It blocks the thread, hence GUI parts in that threat as well. Try to use event scheduler, `after` instead

Comment: @Nae I want to use the least amount of resources possible for the spinner, as it is generally used when my program is doing processor intensive calculations. And what do you mean by blocking gui? It seems to be fine prior to pressing the stop button

Comment: All I'm saying is what you want is achievable w/o threading.

Comment: I don't see how. I want a child window to be constantly updating its gui until the parent thread finishes calculations. When the main thread finishes its calculations, I want the child window to terminate itself at the request of main thread. I do not know how long the calculations will take, so how is after useful?

Comment: `after` can recursively check wether or not if the calculation is done, if not move the bar a step periodically, if done, then destroy the bar entirely. How is this different?

Comment: So I experimented with after (I am not sure how the functionality works, but I am hoping it does not freeze the main program while waiting). I am now running into new problems such as gui not updating and main root freezing when quitting the spinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166084/discussion-between-nae-and-yaroslav).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't measure the progress and just want to show it's busy, and user is not supposed to do other things meanwhile, just change the window mouse cursor to a watch:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> root = tkinter.Tk()
>>> root.configure(cursor='watch')
```

and revert in the end with

```
>>> root.configure(cursor='arrow')
```

you can adapt this to your code and is about as simple as I can think.